# Cache SpringBoot can not test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, caching

I have spring boot application with cache WITHOUT db(jpa, repository etc). Have MyCache class

```
@CachePut(cacheNames = "val", key = "#a1.toString() + #a2.toString()")
public LocalDateTime put(UUID a1, UUID a2, LocalDateTime time) {
    return createdAt;
}

@Cacheable(cacheNames = "val", key = "#a1.toString() + #a2.toString()")
public LocalDateTime get(UUID a1, UUID a2) {
    return LocalDateTime.MIN;
}
```

And I can not test this((
I tried to use Autowired CacheManager in test. But it does not help. In all cases returned method value(LocalDateTime.MIN) instead of cached value.
Please help.

UPDATE: +test code

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class Test {
    MyCache cache = new MyCache();
    @Test
    public void test() {
        UUID a1 = UUID.randomUUID();
        UUID a2 = UUID.randomUUID();
        Assertions.assertEquals(cache.put(a1, a2), cache.get(a1, a2));
    }
}
```

Comment: And we should know how you are testing this, without having code and configuration?

Comment: @M.Deinum add test. I've tried different ways, it is one of those

Comment: Ofcourse that won't work. You will need to autowire the bean for caching to be applied.

Comment: @M.Deinum CacheManager? I've already tried to autowire CacheManager, and than call get()

Comment: No your service injecting the cachemanager won't help.

Comment: @M.Deinum so? what bean should autowire?

Comment: `MyCache` that is what you want to test.

Comment: @M.Deinum exactly

Comment: sigh. For the last time the bean you want to test, `MyCache` is **the one** you need to inject.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, i understand) thank you